# Which Snowflake privilege allow a ROLE to insert/write into a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a `table_aa` created by `ROLE_A` under `my_database.shema_1`. Now, I have another `ROLE_B`, which has `CREATE TABLE` and `USAGE` privilege on `my_database.shema_1`, as well as `SELECT` on tables under `my_database.shema_1`. Then, is `ROLE_B` able to `insert` data into `table_aa`, which is owned and created by `ROLE_A`?

I understand since table_aa's ownership is ROLE_A, so ROLE_B can't drop table_aa. But could ROLE_B write into table_aa?

I'm new to the snowflake. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. `ROLE_B` can't drop/insert into `table_aa` since it is owned by `ROLE_A`.

I understand where your confusion lies. In your case, since `ROLE_B` has `CREATE TABLE` and `USAGE` `SELECT` on tables privilege on `my_database.shema_1`, it is not sufficient for this role to insert or drop tables owned by other roles. Now, since `ROLE_B` has the `CREATE TABLE` privilege, any new table created by this role, will be owned by `ROLE_B` and likewise, `ROLE_A` can't insert/drop the tables owned by this role unless specific permissions are given.

In your case, as suggested by @srinath you need to grant INSERT privilege to `ROLE_B`

```
grant insert on table my_database.shema_1.table_aa to role ROLE_B;
```

For an object owned by a role, the owner role has to grant necessary privileges to the objects in order to perform specific operations using another role.

To verify what all the privileges a role has, run `show grants to role;` similarly to check all the privileges a particular table has been assigned run `show grants on table my_database.shema_1.table_name;` This will show all the privileges the table has and assigned to which role.

Refer to [snowflake-access-control-model](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html) and [security-access-control-privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html) for more clarifications

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide insert privilege to Role_B on table_aa to be able to write to it.